# Joining points to polygons (Tobacco Retailers to census tracts)

Tags: arcmap, geographically-weighted-regression

I'm attempting to join points to polygons but I fear it is severely skewing my analysis. I did a spatial join to join the retailers to their respective tracts. However, when I do spatial analysis tests with demographic data, I get a very low R2 value (.01). I have a compliance score for my tobacco retailers (0, .5 and 1) want to do an analysis of the scores and how they relate to various demographics.

Any advice on joining the points to polygons or anything else?

Comment: Have you attempted any kind of QA on the results like spot-checking individual tracts? Also, make sure that you don't have any points selected. Depending on your method, you might be joining only part of the dataset.

Comment: Hey Mike. How many explanatory variables are you using? Just for clarification: is your dependent variable a compliance score for tobacco retailers and your explanatory variables are demographic variables (maybe income, median age, number of smokers, etc.)? Why do you think your results are wrong? Are you sure you shouldn't just use a normal regression rather than geographical regression model (Do the coordinates matter)?